# How to refresh a tabbed activity when you change and go back to the grade tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

[image]

There's any tutorial/code for refreshing tab? When you change a tab activity and when you go back after you add a new data. It automatically refresh and added.

Below is my `MainActivity` Code,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(mViewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_news_feed);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_grade);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_profile);

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new NewsFeedFragment());
        adapter.addFragment(new LatestGradeFragment());
        adapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment());
        //adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you will have to added dynamically. Nothing automatically added

Comment: Are you using `Tabs` with `View Pager`?

Comment: You can use the interface to identify which tab you are currently on and then highlight the current tab accordingly.

Comment: @SagarZala yes sir, I'm using tabs with view pager

Comment: Post your code in which you initialize ViewPager

Comment: @SagarZala I already post my code

Comment: Ok remove your answer I edited your question with code

Comment: @SagarZala I already delete

Comment: @SagarZala can you send me the code?

Comment: In image I see 2 tabs and in code there 3 tab setup. Why?

Comment: @SagarZala there's 3 tab.
try it again.

Comment: Try `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`